# how to upload an image to server using multi form data in c#? especially in monotouch.iOS

Tags: c#, image-uploading

i  want to upload an image to php server. i dont know how to do it. i tried with below codes

```
System.Net.WebClient Client = new System.Net.WebClient ();
Client.Headers.Add("Content-Type","binary/octet-stream
byte[] result = Client.UploadFile ("http://your_server/upload.php","POST","C:\test.jpg
String s = System.Text.Encoding .UTF8 .GetString (result,0,result.Length );
```

but image shouldn't reach php. i want to use multipart/form data method. can anyone guide me?